# Ajax form not getting results

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have home page with a search feature. Searching from the home page works fine, but when I try to search again using the ajax form (on url.com/search?id=biology) I get redirected to a 404 page saying `/Search` is not found.

Form on home page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.id, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

My Ajax Form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchResult" }))
{
     <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The id field is required." id="id" name="id" type="search" value="@Request.QueryString["id"]" />
     <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}

@Html.Partial("_Results", Model)
```

EDIT: This is the html source for the ajax form that is generated.

```
<form action="/Search" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#searchResult" id="form0" method="post">                        
    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The id field is required." id="id" name="id" type="search" value="biology" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

     <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-10">
         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
     </div>
</form>
```

EDIT 2: From looking at the developers tools, it shows that a POST call is happening. How do I change it to GET for this ajax form?

Comment: I think you forgot yo add the Action and the Controller names  `@Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new AjaxOptions { ... })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@User456789 If you will look at the generated forms in both cases then you will notice that `action` of your Ajax form will be different from your home page form. This is because you did not mention the `Controller` and `Action` in your Ajax helper as mentioned in the comment above. So change your Ajax form code like below and it should work as expected:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchResult" }))
{
    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The id field is required." id="id" name="id" type="search" value="@Request.QueryString["id"]" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: it still gives the same error , `http://localhost:54286/Search` 404 error. I edited the question, with what html is generated.

Comment: @User456789 If you made sure that you have a `Search` controller with `Index` action in it. Then try seeing whether if you hit the breakpoint. Because your code is working for me as expected.

Comment: @User456789 Also I noticed that your homepage form's request method is `GET` while Ajax form's method is `POST` so if you have `[HttpGet]` annotation over your `Index` action in `Search` controller it will return 404.

Comment: Am I supposed to have a `[HttpGet]` and a `[HttpPost]` method? I want the url to show the values.

Comment: @User456789 You cannot have the url show the search term in your Ajax form as it is happening under the hood. For testing purposes, you can remove any annotation on your action and see if it gets hit in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchResult" }))
```

To:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchResult" }))
```

You need to point the form to the correct action in the MVC controller. Make sure `Index` exists and returns `Content`.

Comment: it still gives the same error , `http://localhost:54286/Search` 404 error. I edited the question, with what html is generated.

Comment: I bet it's not firing any Ajax. `method="post"` tells the browser to send a POST request. But, this should get overridden by JavaScript. I would make sure that a click event is getting captured when you submit the form.